# Is there any code editor in MS Azure something similar to Google Cloud

Tags: azure, code-editor, azure-cloud-shell

I am looking for writing python code from inside of MS Azure cloud environment However I couldn't get any option. I am looking for something similar to Google Cloud where I can open Code editor from cloud shell.

Comment: Not sure about Python, but I do know there's an editor available, for instance for App Services: `https://<app_service_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev`

Comment: There's `vim` in https://shell.azure.com if you're looking for trash panda playground.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

1. In [shell.azure.com](https://shell.azure.com/) ,Type `touch test.py` to create a .py file.
2. Type `vim test.py` to open the editor then click button **i** to enter the editor mode.
3. Execute the Python file. Type `python test.py`

My output is as below:

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please accept it as an answer, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code is also now available from Cloud Shell.

At the prompt you can type:

`code test.py`

and it will open the file in a version of Code. Save / exit from Code using the ellipses in the top right corner of the editor.